# Finding the points where a circle intersects an axis

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles, coordinate-systems, quadratics

A circle has the equation:

> *x²+y²+4x-2y-11 = 0*

What would be the coordinates of the points where the circle intersects with the y-axis and how would you calculate it?

Comment: substitute $x=0$ and solve the equation in $y$.

Comment: https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090115155833AAmSAr2

Comment: I'm just starting coordinate geometry and was having a few doubts. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+y^2+4x-2y-11=0$

The points of intersection with the $y$ axis are when $x=0$. Thus, plug in $x=0$ and solve.

$$0^2+y^2+4(0)-2y-11=0$$
$$y^2-2y-11=0$$
Use the quadratic formula: $\large\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ where $a=1, b=-2, c=-11$

$$\frac{-(-2)\pm \sqrt{4-(-44)}}{2}$$
$$\frac{2\pm \sqrt{48}}{2}$$

$\sqrt{48}=\sqrt{8\cdot 6}=\sqrt{4\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 2}=4\sqrt{3}$

$$\frac{2\pm 4\sqrt{3}}{2}=1\pm 2\sqrt{3}$$

So, your coordinates for intersection with the $y$-axis are: $(0,1+ 2\sqrt{3})$ and $(0,1- 2\sqrt{3})$

Answer (score 1):

**Method1:**

Given equation is $(x+2)^2+(y-1)^2=(4)^2$.

Now y-axis corresponds to $x=0$, let it intersect y-axis at $(0,k)$,So , $$(y-1)^2=16-4=12\\
y-1=\pm2\sqrt3\\
y=1\pm2\sqrt3$$

---

**Method2:**

Given circle:
$$x^2+y^2+4x-2y-11 = 0$$
Now y-axis corresponds to $x=0$, so let it intersect y-axis at $(0,k)$:
$$k^2-2k-11=0$$
Using quadratic formula:
$$k=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{2^2-(-2)(11)}}{2(1)}=1+2\sqrt3,1-2\sqrt3$$